# En HTML, ¿Cómo puedo adaptar el contenido al ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: css, html5

Si muestro la página a tamaño completo del monitor, el contenido sale centrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando Chrome, ahora cambio el tamaño del navegador para mostrar el tamaño de pantalla más pequeño, y el contenido no muestra el resultado que intento sacar.

La imagen del Quijote es la única que se muestra al ancho de la pantalla, lo botones y el texto no se muestra del ancho de la pantalla, y tampoco se muestran centrados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con otras opciones, como crear un estilo para body `body{width:100%;}` pero no me ha funcionado.

Éste es el código con el que estoy probando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Prueba centrado</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" /> -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
     crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
   
  <style type="text/css">
      @media (min-width:320px)  { 
      /* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */
          body, table, p, img {
          padding-right: 1em;
          width: 100%;
          }
       }
      @media (min-width:480px)  { 
      /* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ 
      }
      @media (min-width:600px)  { 
      /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ 
      }
      @media (min-width:801px)  { 
      /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 
      }
      @media (min-width:1025px) { 
      /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
      }
      @media (min-width:1281px) { 
      /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
      }
  </style>    </head>

<!-- <body id="content"> -->
<body> 

<center>
<br><br>
<div> 
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td width="130px"> 
            <p align="center"><a href="mnk_17_3.htm"> <img src="Imagen1.png"></a></td>
                
            <td width="130px"> 
            <p align="center"><a href="mnk_17_2.htm"> <img src="Imagen2.png"></a></td>

            <td width="130px"> 
            <p align="center"><a href="mnk_17_1.htm"> <img src="Imagen3.png"></a></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<img src="quijote.jpg">

<br>
<br>
<font size="4" color="red">Don Quijote soy, y mi profesión la de andante caballería. Son mis leyes, el deshacer entuertos, prodigar el bien y evitar el mal. Huyo de la vida regalada, de la ambición y la hipocresía, y busco para mi propia gloria la senda más angosta y difícil. ¿Es eso, de tonto y mentecato?.</font> 

</center>

<br>
<br>
<font size="4" color="blue">Don Quijote soy, y mi profesión la de andante caballería. Son mis leyes, el deshacer entuertos, prodigar el bien y evitar el mal. Huyo de la vida regalada, de la ambición y la hipocresía, y busco para mi propia gloria la senda más angosta y difícil. ¿Es eso, de tonto y mentecato?.</font> 

</body>
</html>
```

Dejo el código en este enlace:

https://jsfiddle.net/SoCu/a4hp5cg2/
https://jsfiddle.net/SoCu/a4hp5cg2/21/

Comment: como sugerencia  te recomiendo usar porcentajes para la maquetación de sitios web , lo otro , tratar de utilizar css aparte no incluido en el html ya que genera ruido.

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que los textos inferiores no son párrafos y, por lo tanto, no les afecta el CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estas bien agregando **100%**, sólo que agrégalo también en las otras etiquetas.

Agrega estos estilos personalizados para cada resolución.

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { 
/* smartphones, portrait iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones (Android) */
    table, p, img {
    padding-right: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    }
 }
@media (min-width:480px)  { 
/* smartphones, Android phones, landscape iPhone */ 
}
@media (min-width:600px)  { 
/* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, e-readers (Nook/Kindle), landscape 800x480 phones (Android) */ 
}
@media (min-width:801px)  { 
/* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 
}
@media (min-width:1025px) { 
/* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
}
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
/* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
}
```

Asegúrate de tener la siguiente meta en tu **head** para que te funcionen los **@media**.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Gracias a los dos por responder, me estaba marchando cuando he visto vuestra respuesta y la curiosidad de probar a podido más, jeje, Armando he probado con el código que dices, y se muestra bien si la pantalla es de un móvil, aunque para mi gusto diría que está pegado al lado derecho http://funkyimg.com/i/2KcqG.png el problema es cuando se muestra en una pantalla mayor de PC, o bien en una Tablet puesta en horizontal, en ese caso tendría que quedar en su tamaño original porque no se ve muy bien http://funkyimg.com/i/2KcqV.png -- P.D. no me deja votar ahora me muestra un error en la votación.

Comment: @SoCu Modifique la respuesta en base a los datos que proporcionas en tú comentario.

Comment: He modificado el codigo del primer post, a ver si es asi como dices, estoy probando y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, salvo que ahora no se muestra pegado al lado derecho, pero cuando la pagina o pantalla es mas grande se sigue viendo las imágenes mayor de su tamaño real, también he código que pones en....  **body, table, p, img......** he puesto el **body**, aunque he probado a ponerlo y quitarlo, y tengo el mismo resultado

Answer (score 1):

```
img { 
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

De esa forma la imagen se adapta..
Te recomiendo buscar información sobre `background-size: cover;` también

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Hernan, podrías poner el código para ver donde estoy metiendo la pata asta que responda Hernan, porque no consigo que al poner la pagina a un tamaño mayor que la pantalla de un móvil se vea bien, se sigue mostrando a un tamaño superior del origial, y se ve fatal.

Comment: Hola, anoche como os comente no conseguía poner bien la pagina, hoy sin hacer nada cuando he abierto el navegador, como lo cerré con la pagina puesta, pues me ha mostrado la pagina que deje anoche en el navegador y para sorpresa se ha mostrado bien el contenido, no puedo hacer pruebas para ver que ha pasado, y porque ahora sin hacer nada se muestra bien, lo comento para que de momento no probéis nada, hasta que pueda ver si en realidad funciona, aunque si es verdad que quite algunos códigos, pero aun así anoche no se mostraba bien el contenido.

Comment: Entre vuestras respuestas lo he podido conseguirlo, ahora ya funciona, muchas gracias de verdad. 
En este caso solo quería aplicarlo a una sola página, bueno son varias, pero muestran casi el mismo contenido, y las he creado prácticamente desde el principio, pero creo que me va a venir bien para otras páginas (tengo que probarlo), esas páginas ya están creadas y son más de 200, lo digo por introducir el código como <style> y no tocar nada más, como en los DIV, porque no me veo modificando tantas páginas, así solo modifico automáticamente agregando este style encima del <head>

Comment: Quiero dar las tres respuestas como buenas, pero solo me deja aceptar una, **me gustaría poder marcar las tres como buenas, o aceptadas que resolvieron el problema**

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que hago es esto:

Creo un div contenedor, el cual dejo al x% (generalmente uso 80%, para que, a los lados, me quede un 10% de distancia entre el borde del navegador y el contenido) y luego lo centro con un "margin: 0 auto;". Dentro de este contenedor creo todo con un ancho del 100%.

Al llegar a formato celular (yo ocupo los 600px como referencia) dejo el .contenedor (el div anterior), al 90% de ancho. .

Espero te ayude mi respuesta.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
   background: #ececec;
  font-family: 'arial', sans serif;
}
.contenedor {
  background: #fafafa;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.contenedor img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:600px)  { 
  .contenedor {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://tuee-v2ighht7nwbriwwue.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Quijote-molinos.jpg"> 
  <h3>Capitulo I</h3>
  <h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </h4>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec mauris eget arcu fringilla imperdiet in eget orci. Cras eu semper urna. Suspendisse lobortis vestibulum dolor, vitae eleifend erat dictum sed. Sed consequat facilisis turpis, in tempus risus aliquet ut. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```